# Modify Express sessions on set and get

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

I'm wondering if there's a way to (globally via Express middleware) intercept the get and set of session objects.

So, for instance if somewhere in one of my controllers I set `req.session.foo = 'bar'` I can change `bar` to `baz`, then when `req.session.foo` is accessed I can send back `bar`.

Comment: Is there a really useful use case for this? Why should a value should be modified twice, on creation and on access?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you should take a look at [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) middleware to store messages in requests.

**From the docs:**

```
app.get('/flash', function(req, res){
  // Set a flash message by passing the key, followed by the value, to req.flash().
  req.flash('info', 'Flash is back!')
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // Get an array of flash messages by passing the key to req.flash()
  res.render('index', { messages: req.flash('info') });
});
```